# Import a repo from one private azure devops org to my private org if I have permissions to both

Tags: git, import, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have just begun to use Azure DevOps and in an attempt to start My colleague and I created our own private Orgs with our own projects. For example my project would be Dennis_org/my_first_project and his is J_org/his_first_project. I am a member on his with permissions to create repo's in his project and vice versa.

However, as a test, we both tried to import each other's private repo's inside our project to each other's project.

[image]

I try to import by:

> 1) going to my project
>
> 2) going to files/import a repository which triggers the picture above.
>
> 3) copying both the git address and the https address from his repo, and trying to import. I get the error below:

[image]

I have tried many variations of web addresses or git addresses but none seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not both just using the same source repo if you're collaborating?

Comment: Because we work in a department with multiple groups and we are trying to determine how easy something like this would be if one private group wanted to share with another.

Comment: i think url should be: `https://dev.azure.com/PROJECT/repo/_git/repo` not `PROJECT/repo/_git` or at least something like that, in my case url is `project/repo/_git/repo`

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that you need to authorize the import request: make sure you check the "Requires Authorization" checkbox and provide a PAT with enough permissions for the other organization:

Generate the PAT:

[image]

Copy it to the clipboard:

[image]

And supply that in the password/PAT box in the import dialog:

[image]

Then grab the clone URL from the source repo and put that in as well:

[image]

That should do the trick.