# Fork a repo from one Azure DevOps Org to another Org using the API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

Is it possible to fork a repo that exists in a Private Project of the SourceOrganization into another Project of DestOrganization using Azure DevOps API?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973536/azure-devops-import-a-repo-from-one-private-org-to-my-private-org-if-i-have-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No this is not available.

The question you linked to will allow you to create a one-time mirror of another repository, but you won't have any features like pull requests, diff/merge etc.

You can perform an import request to create a clone in another organization, but it completely ignores the relationship between the repos and you can't perform any pull requests across the organisations.

The code is two-step:

1. Create a temporary endpoint using a PAT that has at least `Code (Read)` access on the source organisation.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{{ORG}}/{{PROJECT}}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints

{
    "authorization":{
        "parameters":{
            "password":"{{PAT WITH ENOUGH PERMISSIONS}}",
            "username":"."
        },
        "scheme":"UsernamePassword"
    },
    "name":"{{RANDOM UNIQUE NAME}}",
    "type":"git",
    "url":"{{CLONE URL OF SOURCE REPO}}"
}
```

which will respond with an endpoint ID:

```
{
   "data":{},
   "id":"72d574f0-05f1-481f-af15-f78579b374d4",
   "name":"wv1w1",
   "type":"git"
   ...
}
```

2. Then create the import:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{{ORG}}/{{PROJECT}}/_apis/git/repositories/{{NEW REPO NAME}}/importRequests

{
   "parameters":{ 
      "deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone":true,
      "gitSource":{
          "overwrite":false,
          "url":"{{CLONE URL OF SOURCE REPO}}"
      },
      "tfvcSource":null,
      "serviceEndpointId":"{{ID FROM PREVIOUS REQUEST}}"
    }
}
```

It also can't be used to sync sources between different organisations.

You could cobble something together with a Azure Pipeline that pushes the changes from one org to another. Again, no "fork", but really just a sync.

Comment: Got it. One question. Can you please confirm if  source repo ({{CLONE URL OR SOURCE REPO}}) could exists in the Private project?

Comment: As long as you setup the PAT with appropriate access for the private project, things work on my end without issues.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explicitly mention (in your answer) that the PAT must be created in Source Org/Project so that it's clear for everyone? :-)